# Ninject can't bind an enum property to a filter

Tags: c#, enums, ninject, ninject.web

I have an MVC attribute set up like this:

```
public class Activity : FilterAttribute
{
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public Directive Directive { get; set; }
}
```

and a corresponding filter class

```
public class ActivityFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public ActivityFilter(IService service, IEnumerable<string> tags, Directive directive)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

My bindings for the attribute to filter injection look like this:

```
this.BindFilter<ActivityFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
  .WhenActionMethodHas<Activity>()
  .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Activity>("tags", a => a.Tags)
  .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Activity>("directive", a => a.Directive);
```

When I try to debug my web site, I get an error from Ninject stating that it can't activate the ActivityFilter because no matching bindings are available for int, specifically:

> ActivationException: Error activating int
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>
> > 2) Injection of dependency int into parameter directive of constructor of type ActivityFilter
> >
> > 1) Request for ActivityFilter

It seems like Ninject is misinterpreting the enumeration parameter for an integer, but I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the method I was using for binding:

```
this.BindFilter<ActivityFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
   .WhenActionMethodHas<Activity>()
   .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Activity>("tags", a => a.Tags)
   .WithPropertyValueFromActionAttribute<Activity>("directive", a => a.Directive);
```

I should have used `WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute` since I was trying to inject into a constructor argument (I mistakenly thought that the Constructor/Property referred to the *source* of the value, not the *destination*.)

Once I changed this it worked fine.